# rename multiple folder to Uppercase not files using powershell

Tags: powershell, file-rename, uppercase, batch-rename

I am working on powershell where I have multiple folders i need to change all folders names into Uppercase not the files only folder.

I have tried the below code

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Xyz\Desktop\sample" -Recurse | % { 
  if ($_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToUpper()) { ren $_.FullName $_.Name.ToUpper() } 
}
```

But with this code it was changing only file name but I want to change only dir

for example

[image]

foldername (lowerCase)

```
abc
cab
dab
```

like this (UPPERCASE)

```
ABC
CAB
DAB
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These tricks may not be obvious.  How's this?  Hmm, that didn't actually work.  You can't rename folders to the same thing in upper case in powershell.

```
# doesn't work!
get-childitem -recurse -directory -path "C:\Users\Xyz\Desktop\sample" | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name.toupper() } -whatif
```

Sometimes calling cmd from powershell just works better.  Try this first as a "whatif" to see if it does what you want.  And if I really understand the question.  All this does is echo strings.  This command is just "pretend".

```
get-childitem -recurse -directory -path "C:\Users\Xyz\Desktop\sample" | 
  foreach { write-host cmd /c ren $_.fullname $_.name.toupper() }
```

And if that looks good, this actually does the rename.  But maybe make a backup in case something goes wrong.  Be able to undo the action.

```
get-childitem -recurse -directory -path "C:\Users\Xyz\Desktop\sample" | 
  foreach { cmd /c ren $_.fullname $_.name.toupper() }
```

Comment: +1 for a pragmatic workaround. It's worth mentioning that creating a `cmd.exe` child process for each input folder is quite expensive, though for occasional renaming that may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

- To **limit `Get-ChildItem`'s output to *directories* only, use the `-Directory` switch** (PSv3+; in PSv2, pipe to `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`
- Apart from that, your solution *should* work, but doesn't due to **a *conceptual flaw* in .NET's `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.MoveTo()` method (and also `System.IO.Directory.Move()` method), which PowerShell's `Rename-Item` cmdlet builds on**, as of .NET Core 3.0 preview6 / .NET 4.8:

  - The method doesn't recognize *case variations* of *directory* name as a *different* name, and fails with `Source and destination path must be different`.

    - Curiously, *files* are not affected, as you've experienced.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Of course, while NTFS is case-*insensitive*, it is also case-*preserving*, so it *should* be possible to rename `foo` to `FOO`, for instance.

    - The problem has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40013).

**Workaround** (PSv4+):

Note: [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57347934/45375) offers another, workaround, based on calling `cmd.exe` for each input folder to use its `ren` command. While it is conceptually simpler, the caveat is that this approach of creating a child process for every folder processed is inefficient and slow. That said, for occasional renaming operations that probably won't matter.

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Xyz\Desktop\sample'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Recurse -Directory |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToUpper() } -PipelineVariable dir |  
    Rename-Item -PassThru -NewName { [IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName() } |
      Rename-Item -NewName { $dir.Name.ToUpper() }
```

The workaround *temporarily* renames matching folders to a transient, randomly generated name (`[IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()`) and *then* applies the all-uppercase version of the original name.

The input folder's original state and name are captured via variable `$dir`, which is "stashed" away for later use via the common `-PipelineVariable` parameter.

---

<sup>[1] Caveat: When you use `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item` to report a specific directory or file by its literal name, whatever case variation *you specify* is reported back, even though the true case variation *as stored in the filesystem* may differ (File Explorer, by contrast, always shows you the true case). To see the true case, use
`Get-ChildItem <parentDir> -Filter <name>`
or, as a quick workaround that may show additional items, however, append `*` to the name/path. In both cases, the name is treated as a wildcard pattern, and the result of the matching process reflects the true case.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

How to double quotes folder names ? Some folders has spaces ...

write-host cmd /c ren $*.fullname $*.name.toupper()

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend this to be run - can you give a better example? I don't see how this would affect folders without affecting files

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer, or a different question?